# MVC : Creating Database using Model class

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I  am following [this](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m4-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building)  MVC tutorial and trying to create a database using DbContext and related model classes. The project name is "odeToFood".

Model classes:

```
namespace odeToFood.Models
{
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string  City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }

    public class RestaurantReview
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    }   

    public class odeToFoodDb :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }

    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        odeToFoodDb _db = new odeToFoodDb(); 

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model= _db.Restaurants.ToList(); 
            return View(model);
        }
   }
```

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<odeToFood.Models.Restaurant>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
          <h4>@item.Name;</h4> 
          Restaurant  is in  : @item.City   &nbsp; @item.Country 
          <hr />
    </div>       
}
```

When I run this code, according to [this tutorial](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m4-data-i&mode=live&clip=2&course=mvc4-building) it should create a database and the values should be fetched (when I enter in table) but in server explorer I cannot find a database.

Neither the Index View gives an error nor can I find a database in server explorer. I tried  `(Localdb)\v11.0`  by going to "add connection" but still it does not show any database.

I would be grateful to know what's wrong.

Comment: Check your config file for the web project, it should contain a connection string which will point to the database, if it has successfully created a db the connection string will point to it.

Comment: did you tried DbMigration with code first ?

Comment: Do you have a sql server express installed? Code Firsts [preferences express over localdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542).

Comment: Can you show us your connection string? As Charleh pointed, it has the information where the DB will be created. By default (Localdb)\v11.0, you can change it to point to local instance to your SQL server.